# Byobu 5.133 does not start up on my mac after a recent upgrade

Tags: macos, tmux, byobu

I'm not sure how to diagnose this issue further. I recently did a brew upgrade of a lot of stuff, one of which was byobu and it fails to even startup spitting out this as the error:

`^[[?62;4c[exited]`

Obviously the upgrade could have installed a dependency that messed things up as well. Any recommendations of where to look? Or what steps to take to root cause the problem?

I tried exporting this variable first which did not change the outcome:

`export BYOBU_RUN_DIR=$HOME/.byobu/run/`

Running tmux does start fine, but not byobu. Any other help is appreciated. If you need me to include any other info let me know.

Byobu version:

```
byobu --version
byobu version 5.133
tmux 3.1
```

Mac version:

```
10.15.4 Catalina
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a version mismatch issue. It turns out the tmux I was defaulting to was an old version, not the one showing when running byobu --version, but one installed by a very old oh-my-zsh plugin. Once I removed the plugin so it pointed to the correct tmux later version everything worked again.

Any tmux command I ran said something like `tmux server version is too old for client` which led me to run `which tmux` which pointed to the old, incorrect version.

Comment: For some reason, for me I got that error whenever I tried to paste (with `p`) in nvim.

I was getting super mad, when I found this, restarted tmux (which I had just upgraded with brew), and gained a renewed appreciation for the mysterious workings of my dev environment.